# how do I convert an existing text element to a d3plus-text textbox?

Tags: d3.js, d3plus

I trying to use d3plus-text. First i append new text element on svg element

```
node.append("text")
.text(function (d: any) { return d.properties.name; })
.attr("class", "nodeText");
```

and then i want to wrap that text

```
new d3PlusText.TextBox()
.select(".nodeText")
.fontResize(true)
.width(options.nodeRadius)
.render();
```

But i am getting error on render

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined
    TextBox.render
    node_modules/d3plus-text/es/src/TextBox.js:130
130 | var boxes = this._select.selectAll(".d3plus-textBox").data(this._data.reduce(function (arr, d, i) {
```

I am certain there are nodeText elements. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is "how do I convert an existing text element to a d3plus-text textbox"?  I don't see that supported in it's documentation.  Why aren't you using it as documented?

Comment: I have that text element and I want to wrap it and autoscale it, so im trying to find a library that can do that for me.